# can i tell mypy to warn me on type ignores without error codes, only *# type: ignore[code, ...]* should be accepted

Tags: mypy

I would like to have all type-ignores with errorcodes `# type: ignore[code, ...]` and disallow `# type: ignore` without them.

I checked the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html?highlight=type%20ignore#silencing-errors-based-on-error-codes) but could not find what I am looking for.

Is there any option that allows me to do that? I could write my own script to do that, but if mypy can do that I would prefer that.

Something like `warn_type_ignore_without_errorcode = True`?

Answer (score 1):

This has been added from mypy 0.40 with the `ignore-without-code` check. Enable it in-code with:

```
# mypy: enable-error-code ignore-without-code
```

Or add it to your pyproject.toml file with:

```
[tool.mypy]
enable_error_code = "ignore-without-code"
```

Or add it to your mypy.ini file with:

```
[mypy]
enable_error_code = ignore-without-code
```

Reference:

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html#check-that-type-ignore-include-an-error-code-ignore-without-code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I added `enable_error_code = "ignore-without-code"` to mypy.ini, but id did not work 
I got `mypy: error: Invalid error code(s): ignore-without-code`

Comment: If you're using a mypy.ini file, you don't need to wrap your strings in double quotes. So you want: `enable_error_code = ignore-without-code`